# Scraping with BS4 but HTML gets messed up when parsed

Tags: python, html, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm having trouble scraping a website using BeautifulSoup4 and Python3. I'm using dryscrape to get the HTML since it requires JavaScript to be enabled in order to be shown (but as far as I know it's never used in the page itself).

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import dryscrape

productUrl = "https://www.mercadona.es/detall_producte.php?id=32009"
session = dryscrape.Session()
session.visit(productUrl)
response = session.body()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")
container1 = soup.find("div","contenido").find("dl").find_all("dt")
container3 = soup.find("div","contenido").find_all("td")
```

Now I want to read `container3` content, but:

```
type(container3)
```

Returns:

```
bs4.element.ResultSet
```

which is the same as `type(container1)`, but it's length it's 0!

So I wanted to know what was I getting to `container3` before looking for my `<td>` tag, so I wrote it to a file.

```
container3 = soup.find("div","contenido")
soup_file.write(container3.prettify())
```

And, here is the link to that file: https://pastebin.com/xc22fefJ

It gets all messed up just before the table I want to scrape. I can't understand why, looking at the URL source code from Firefox everything looks fine.

Comment: Can you use selenium for this?

Comment: @drec4s Yes, I can. Why should I? Isn't selenium a bit over engineered for this situation?

Comment: Edited my answer. It works, but it's a bit slow. May be, choosing an alternative library to run JS code in python will give you better performance. Try PyV8.

Comment: @Mahesh Thank you very much!! I don't mind about speed, maybe I can think about that later. Will try it tomorrow.

Comment: @Mahesh Everything's fine. Thanks a lot again. I'm new at scraping and was clueless about this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the updated solution:

```
url = 'https://www.mercadona.es/detall_producte.php?id=32009'

rh = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Host': 'www.mercadona.es',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36'
}

s = requests.session()
r = s.get(url, headers = rh)
```

The response to this gives you the `Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.` message. However, it also contains the necessary `hidden` data sent by browser using javascript, which can be seen from the network tab of the developer's tools.

```
TS015fc057_id: 3
TS015fc057_cr: a57705c08e49ba7d51954bea1cc9bfce:jlnk:l8MH0eul:1700810263
TS015fc057_76: 0
TS015fc057_86: 0
TS015fc057_md: 1
TS015fc057_rf: 0
TS015fc057_ct: 0
TS015fc057_pd: 0
```

Of these, the second one (the long string) is generated by javascript. We can use a library like `js2py` to run the code, which will return the required string to be passed in the request.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
script = soup.find_all('script')[1].text

js_code = re.search(r'.*(function challenge.*crc;).*', script, re.DOTALL).groups()[0] + '} challenge();'
js_code = js_code.replace('document.forms[0].elements[1].value=', 'return ')

hidden_inputs = soup.find_all('input')
hidden_inputs[1]['value'] = js2py.eval_js(js_code)

fd = {i['name']: i['value'] for i in hidden_inputs}

rh = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Referer': 'https://www.mercadona.es/detall_producte.php?id=32009',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Length': '188',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Host': 'www.mercadona.es',
    'Origin': 'https://www.mercadona.es',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36'
}

# NOTE: the next one is a POST request, as opposed to the GET request sent before
r = s.post(url, headers = rh, data = fd)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
```

And here's the result:

```
>>> len(soup.find('div', 'contenido').find_all('td'))
70
>>> len(soup.find('div', 'contenido').find('dl').find_all('dt'))
8
```

**EDIT**

Apparently, the javascript code needs to be run only once. The resulting data can be used for more than one request, like this:

```
for i in range(32007, 32011):
    r = s.post(url[:-5] + str(i), headers = rh, data = fd)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    print(soup.find_all('dd')[1].text)
```

Result:

```
Manzana y plátano 120 g
Manzana y plátano 720g (6x120) g
Fresa Plátano 120 g
Fresa Plátano 720g (6x120g)
```

Comment: Hi, I can't replicate your results. I get:

    TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()

Are you using a Requests session? Thank you, I'm sorry if it's a trivial question.

Comment: @EngineeringStudent you're probably passing the response object to len. First create a soup object with it, and then navigate the tree. `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')` and then try the statements in my answer. I'll edit my answer to include that statement, for clarity.

Comment: Let me show you the full code I'm running and the full output: https://pastebin.com/f6mtnDqA
What I'm getting is a page that asks me to enable javascript in order to show what I want to scrap.e
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @EngineeringStudent I'm looking at it right now. It worked for me then. Will edit the answer as soon as I figure this out.